# What is the difference between hostname -i and ip addr linux command

Tags: 18.04, virtualization, ip-address

I wasted almost an entire day figuring out why my newly created vm hasn't been allocated an ip address. I was using the command `hostname -i` which returned 127.0.1.1, however, after using `ip addr` I could finally get hold of my vm's ip address.

Can someone please explain to me why `hostname -i` did not return the ip address? Is it because the VM is built into my HOST machine and the hostname command operates on the host and not virtualized machine?

Answer (score 0):

From the man page of the `hostname` command:

```
Hostname is used to display the system's DNS name, and to display or set its hostname or NIS domain name.
```

From the man page of the `ip` command:

```
ip - show / manipulate routing, network devices, interfaces and tunnels
```

When you run the `hostname -i` command it shows you the IP associated with the system name and not the IP address associated with the network card for which the `ip addr` or `ip a` command is correct.

The hostname command is directly linked to the content of the `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` files.

**Example to understand:**

Let's suppose that my hostname is "linux123" and that only IP 192.168.0.3 provided **dynamically** by DHCP is associated to the eth0 network card, let's also suppose that I'll have to install a vpn in the future and that I'll be associated with the **static** IP 172.20.0.5

I now add the following line to the `/etc/hosts` file:

> 172.20.0.5 linux123

Now if I launch the `hostname -i` command, the answer will be

> 127.0.1.1 172.20.0.5

In practice now the system already knows it's 172.20.0.5 even though the VPN is not yet installed and therefore the tun0 interface with the IP does not yet exist; this is because I mapped the IP address into the local system name resolution system (`/etc/hosts`).

Why didn't I add 192.168.0.3?
Because it is an address that could change and mapping it "permanently" to my system name can lead to errors/problems in the future.

Comment: When you say IP associated with the system name, what exactly do you mean? can you please elaborate on this more?

Comment: @Sagar Shroff: I mean that the system shows you the address that is mapped in the local system name resolution services; "system name" and "hostname" are two ways to refer to the same thing, it was to avoid confusion with the `hostname` command.
I added an example in the answer that I hope will help you understand better.